# Controller helpers in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am new to rails and am wondering if this is the best way to go about what I want to do.

I have a controller that creates entities.

Depending what gets submitted I want to either create a new entity from scratch, or copy an existing one.

So far I have

```
def create
  if(params[:copy])
    return copy_existing_entity params
  else
    return create_new_entity params
  end
end
```

So far this feels icky - should this be done differently?

Coming from java spring, I would just define separate handlers on the controller like so:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params="submit=Action 1")
public ModelAndView action1(@RequestParam("selectedItemKey") String key) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("action1");
    //Business logic
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params="submit=Action 2")
public ModelAndView action2(@RequestParam("selectedItemKey") String key) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("action2");
    //Business logic
    return mav;
}
```

Does rails provide something like this or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does seem kind of bad. First of all, why are you copying entities in the first place? What's your use case?

Second, you're probably putting the logic in the wrong place. You should probably either (1) have separate `create` and `copy` controller actions, or (2) pass `params` on to the model class and let it figure out whether it's creating or copying.

Comment: If I add a copy action to my controller, is that triggered by a different route by default or do I need to specify a parameter. My understanding was ruby triggered different actions based on the HTTP verb of which I only have 4...

Comment: You can trigger your controller actions any way you like. I'd probably give it a separate route (i.e. a custom REST action), but that's up to you. Think about what URLs would be best for the UI you're trying to create. And again: what's your use case?

Comment: To clarify: Rails routing looks at *both* the HTTP verb and the URL.

Comment: The user has built a tree of data using a graphical interface which is persisted in the database. In the copy scenario I want to take this tree and build a list which will be persisted as a separate entity that the user can edit without changing the original tree.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand, but that seems bizarre. If the list is exported from the tree, shouldn't it stay tied to the original tree if at all possible?

Comment: This was a design decision that was considered. However the view is that they are "exporting" the tree to the list. The requirement is for changes in one not to effect the other... Thanks for the help anyway - looks like a custom route is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, probably. Perhaps the URL should have `export` instead of `copy`, though, if that's what's significant to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily split it apart in two controller actions, but actually I do believe that in both cases you are creating a new Entity. So a `POST :create` is the good REST way. And if you have to create a new item filled up with the given attributes, or create a new item as a copy from another does not really matter imho.